# How to block all requests starting with "?mode" on Apache?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wordpress, hacking

Recently my website was hacked and now I have around 20000 indexed links in Google that were redirected to other sites via my website. Now I have stopped all redirects but I have too many request on my host. All indexed links in Google are something like this:

- `example.com/?mode=list1124413.html`
- `example.com/?mode=grid125761916.html`

I want to block all requests starting with `?mode` but I don't know why these configurations I have tried are not working:

```
RewriteCond     %{QUERY_STRING} ".*(?:^|&)mode=(?:=|&|$)"
RewriteRule     "" "-" [F]

RedirectMatch 404 ^?mode/\d+$
RedirectMatch 404 ^mode\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to match *query strings* with [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html):

> [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks. For more complicated tasks such as manipulating the query string, use the tools provided by [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

A working configuration with [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} "(^|&)mode="
RewriteRule    "" "-" [F]
```